# Trailhead : Lightning Web Components basic error when deploying

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, trailhead

Can't create lightning component bundle if there is already an aura definition bundle with the same name and namespace.
Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle paginator.
force-app\main\default\flexipages\Order_Record_Page.flexipage-meta.xml  We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component c:productTileList.                                                 No MODULE named markup://c:paginator found : [markup://c:productTileList]

Comment: Hi - which trialhead are you trying to complete?  Can you provide a link?  Also, try taking a snapshot of your folder structure

Comment: the link is hear, so i have fixed the bugs. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/handle-events-in-lightning-web-components?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Lightning Aura Component with the name paginator, probably from another Trailhead module. Delete that component first before attempting to deploy a Lightning Web Component with the same name.

Comment: thanks. i will try it.

Comment: i have delete the paginator component but i have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. But here is how I fixed a similar issue after checking that there is no duplicate. The package.xml was missing the category. After adding this, everything started working:

```
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
```